# Make AJAX call from Handlebars template?

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am building an SPA on Mongoose, Node, Backbone stack and using Handlebars. A user signs up for one or more courses. Then, user can go to his list of courses and cancel if he chooses. The API works, I can remove the courses from the database making an ajax call to the specific url from the console. The problem is I need the ajax call to take the variable from the handlebars template. How do I capture the {{_id}} from my handlebars template and pass it into an AJAX delete request that is outside the template?

```
template: Handlebars.compile(

    '<h4>{{local.petname}} is a busy beast!</h4>'+
    '<h2>Upcoming Courses: </h2>' +
    '<ul>'+
        '{{#each signup}}' +
            '<li><h3>{{name}}</h3>{{coursDay}}{{time}}{{location}}</li>' +
            '<a href="/test/signups/{{_id}}" data-id="{{_id}}""  class="btn btn-danger confirm-delete">Remove Course</a><br/><br/>' +
            '<li>{{_id}}</li>'+
        '{{/each}}'+
    '</ul>'

),
```

Here is my ajax request; attrID returns the ObjectID of only the first item in the array

```
deleteItem: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var attrID = $('.btn-danger').data();
    console.log(attrID);

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/test/signups/" + attrID, 
    type: "DELETE",

    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
      console.log("Post response:"); 
      console.dir(data); 
      console.log(textStatus); 
      console.dir(jqXHR); 
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little unsure where you want to call your `deleteItem()` function, but the issue is with the jQuery selector:

`$('.btn-danger')` selects all your links. You get them back in a jQuery wrapped list. The method `data()` is then only applied to the first item of your list, thus resulting only in your first node. You should also provide the parameter `'id'`, otherwise you again will get an array.

Assuming you want all links to do the AJAX call, you can call:

```
$('.btn-danger').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var attrID = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(attrID);

  $.ajax({ ... });
});
```

Edit: replaced `$(...).live()` (deprecated) with `$(...).on()`.

---

There also is an issue with your handlebars template `data-id="{{_id}}""` the second quotes should be removed.

Comment: I swapped out "live" for "on" - working now. Thanks!

Comment: I did edit my initial answer to reflect the deprecation.